# Equivalent of Event Log in Linux

Tags: linux, crash, event-log

Is there an equivalent to the Windows Event Log in Linux? When services crash or processes running in disconnected session explode, where's the problem logged to?

More specifically, if a Java JVM app dies, where does the JVM write to? On Windows, there's the WER system that collects crash telemetry ([more info](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/02/05/ws2008-windows-error-reporting.aspx)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe /var/log directory is what you need. There are many log files by default.

Comment: Lots of stuff in here. Is there any particular file I should look at for general app/crash type events?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "die"? If it e.g. segfaults, yuo might find something as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219524/linux-var-log-syslog-segfault-message-format-what-does-each-parameter-means) in /var/log/syslog.
Otherwise a crashed process might leave you with a [core dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump). I'm not sure if and where *java* itself performs "voluntary" logging if it is not java tha crashes but an app that java runs, but indeed tha java process would be the one responsible for logging java-specific info about problems with its daughter processes.

Comment: /var/log/syslog doesn't seem to exist on this VM (CentOS). I can't list it or cat it.

Comment: @LukePuplett I don't know specifically about CentOS, but other typical names for general logging may be called `/var/log/messages`. More about log files locations may be learned from `/etc/syslog.conf` (including the possibility that logging is disabled or redirected to a remote host)